# Как переключить activity при отсутствии интернета?

Tags: java, android, webview

Все привет.
Как переключать activity при отсутствии интернета?

Есть простой webview с ссылкой на сайт.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClietn());
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
    }
}
```

и есть еще класс TryNetwork

```
    public class TryNetwork {
    public static boolean check() {
        Runtime localRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        boolean bool = false;
        try {
            int i = localRuntime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8").waitFor();
            if (i == 0) {
            bool = true;
            }
            return bool;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException) {
            localInterruptedException.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        catch (IOException localIOException) {
        localIOException.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

я знаю как переключать экраны простыми кнопками, но тут возникла потребность сделать переключение автоматическим
google не находит ничего ((

вот второй activity

```
    public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button reTry;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

        reTry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reTry);
        reTry.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.reTry:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
                default:
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

и разметка второго activity

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/errConnection"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/err_connection" />

<Button android:id="@+id/reTry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/re_try"
    android:layout_below="@+id/errConnection"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаем класс для проверки соединения

```
public class NetworkUtils {


public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
    if (cm != null) {
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }
    return activeNetwork != null &&
            activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

и далее там где нужно проверить сеть, например, при старте активности в методе `onCreate`

```
if (!NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferenceActivity.class));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно в втором классе использовать экземпляр класса проверки соединения. Дальше если метод этого класса возвращает значение `false` то мы переходим на другое активити. То есть тот переход, что висит на кнопке, просто делать при проверке. Если я правильно понимаю, вам нужно сделать переход с активити `BaseActivity` на `MainActivity`. Значит вы должны в классе проверки соединения, возвращать значение `true` или `false` в зависимости от наличия соединения. Дальше вам нужно будет вызывать метод класса проверки соединения в активити  `BaseActivity` и если соединение отсутствует то делать переход. Не факт что я все правильно написал, но по логике должно работать. Надеюсь чем-то помог. Удачи :)

P.S. Метка `android-studio` используется для вопросов связанных только с самой IDE, а не с тем что вы там создаете. Поэтому в вам бы посоветовал избегать использования неправильных меток, поскольку здесь это не приветствуется :))